# Quickblox - How to register New user in QuickBlox API

Tags: ios, quickblox

I'm new to iOS. I'm using custom authentication. I've checked sample code and i'm confused, how they are updating registered user in user panel while user is logged in.

Please tell How should i use their code, i downloaded and run their sample code but it is outdated and gives so many errors.

My authentication code while log in -

```
- (IBAction)signIn:(id)sender
{
  indicator.center = CGPointMake(160, 200);
  [self.view addSubview:indicator];
  [indicator startAnimating];
  NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:***********************",userName.text,passWord.text];
  NSURL *add = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
  NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:add];
  (void) [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];

 [QBRequest createSessionWithSuccessBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBASession *session)
 {
     // session created
     QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
     //user.password = @"azhhdsf";
     //user.login = @"dsfgsgf";

     user.login =  userName.text;
     user.password = passWord.text;


     // Registration/sign up of User
     [QBRequest signUp:user successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user)
      {
          // Sign up was successful
      } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response)
      {
          // Handle error here
          NSLog(@"error while signing up with QB");
      }];
  }
                              errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response)
  {
     // handle errors
     NSLog(@"%@", response.error);
 }

  ];
 }
```

Getting Thread Error-->

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[QBRequest createSessionWithSuccessBlock:errorBlock:]**

I'm running their sample code for log in **http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-ios#Adding_a_User_Base_to_your_application** but getting error -

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MTBlockAlertView", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in SSUEditViewController.o
   objc-class-ref in SSULoginViewController.o
   objc-class-ref in SSUMainViewController.o
   objc-class-ref in SSURegistrationViewController.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As I'm new to iOS, so i could resolve this errors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must read first a guide how to start using QuickBlox

http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#Oh.2C_please.2C_please_show_me_the_code

As I understand you didn't setup the QuickBlox application properly, that's why you get this exception

Then download Users sample http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-ios
, play with it and read Users sample guide

Comment: Thanks i will look into links given by u... thanks for reply bro

Comment: i m getting error in Users sample, the error is - Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MTBlockAlertView", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in SSUEditViewController.o
   objc-class-ref in SSULoginViewController.o
   objc-class-ref in SSUMainViewController.o
   objc-class-ref in SSURegistrationViewController.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[QBRequest signUp:successBlock:errorBlock:]: getting error while sign up

Comment: @igor-khomenko Is there any example in php for addnig user ?

Comment: @AwladLiton http://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization#PHP http://quickblox.com/developers/Users#User_Sign_Up

Comment: @IgorKhomenko Could you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556005/quickblox-javascript-sdk-one-to-one-video-chat ?

Comment: @IgorKhomenko Hi I am using Quick blocks API in my iOS application, and I am using createSessionWithSuccessBlock method for creating session, but sometimes it gives me error, like it goes to failed block instead of success block. Please tell me why I am getting error block?