# quickblox javascript sdk one to one video chat

Tags: javascript, php, quickblox

I am working in a system for on line solution where two types of user will be available: experts,normal user.
2 things is need to do:

1) after normal user login i want to show a list of expert available in the on line for hangout. Normal user can click one expert from the list and clicked expert will receive one call signal and they can have conversation.

2) I need video call details( caller, receiver, duration, date etc)

I want to do this by javascript sdk. I have [this git repository](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-javascript-sdk).

questions:

1) should i need to add normal users in my application user list in admin panel or only need expert users in user list?

2) I want to implement it like google hangout( call the user frm the contact list it will auto call the receiver no need to connect). How can i implement it? After connected to chat server normal users will have a list of online expert users.

3) is there any php curl example of adding new user in my application user list in admin panel?

sorry if any question is stupid. I am new in quickblox.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are some old samples as examples for your situation.

To see users in the online list after loging to chat, you should check, if they are already exist in your Contact List (Roster) or not, before you can do a call.

Chat example:
http://qblx.co/1y93i3e

Roster logic:
http://qblx.co/1y92n2D

The videocall sample (old version):
http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-videochat-web

The new version is currently under development.

QB does not have PHP SDK or any samples for it, but maybe you will be interested to look at some php snippets:

http://quickblox.com/developers/Generate_session_in_PHP

https://gist.github.com/AndreyPovelichenko/111e84edd482492dc8bf

https://gist.github.com/AndreyPovelichenko/cad2241faa7149e20a7b